# Take only part of a git commit, push to github

Tags: git, github, rebase

I'm a fan of a project on github ([Slippy](https://github.com/Seldaek/slippy)).  Another fork of the project ([by kageroh](https://github.com/kageroh/slippy)) has a commit that I want to push to the original project, but the maintainer doesn't want the whole commit, only part of it.

My understanding is that I could use interactive rebasing to take only part of the commit, but that I shouldn't because it's a commit that is already on a public repository.  Is there a way to take part of the commit, and get it pulled to the original repo with the author's attribution intact?  Or do I just have to copy the changes I want and put them into a new commit under my name?

Comment: Commits are cherry picked to all the time. See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147847/what-do-i-do-when-a-pull-request-is-cherry-picked).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's fine to cherry-pick and reduce that commit.  To set the author of the commit, just use `git commit --author="The Original Author <his@address>"`.

To give an example, if `f414f3l` is the commit that you want to reduce, I would probably do the following:

```
# Make sure you're on the branch you want to create the new commit on:
git checkout master

# Now cherry-pick the commit, but only stage the changes:
git cherry-pick -n f414f3l

# Choose which hunks you want to unstage interactively, using the 's'
# option to split them where necessary.  (Or using the 'e' option for
# complete control over what patch to unstage.)
git reset -p

# When you commit, the commit message should be preserved:
git commit --author="The Original Author <his@address>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the history of a public *branch* is a bad idea, but there is nothing sacrosanct about an individual *commit* that means you can't copy it, modify it and publish it on another branch.

You may just be able to create a new branch based off the upstream master, `cherry-pick` the commit you want to modify and then `commit --amend` to change it. That should preserve authorship.